# Are there any descriptions of the reluctance motor invented by W.H. Taylor in the 1800's?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I could not find any descriptions of the first motors of W. H. Taylor in Wikipedia of any reference, history or circumstances surrounding its invention. Apparently the motor was never used for any applications?

It is used today in I believe the Tesla electric cars but was curious what this animal looked like when Taylor put it together. I assume the motor can use both AC and DC and was versatile but was never worked on? Not sure of the tags on this one or if the question is off topic. Maybe more of an electrical engineering question? I don't know.

Comment: Wikipedia alleges that W. H. Taylor had an 1834 US patent for this, but one of its sources gave no date or patent number, and the other is to a dead link.  I tried to find W. H. Taylor 1800s patents, and found nothing that matched.

Comment: Maybe it is illustrated in https://patents.google.com/patent/US3245610A/

Comment: That's a nice website just the same even if I don't find any reference. A thank you just the same...I guess there is probably no such thing as the historical development of the different types of motors ....I can imagine very little interest in that sort of thing now days.

Comment: There WAS an 1839 English patent: "Improvements in obtaining power by means of electromagnetism”, by William Hannis Taylor, of New York but later Bridge Street, Blackfriars (London) which you could look up, I suppose.

Comment: Interesting. Will do. I believe Tesla motors uses  in it's newer model. The other models use the AC induction with an inverter. But one of the models uses a Switched reluctance motor. but not sure yet

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.eti.kit.edu/english/1376.php , which has a super-brief mention of Taylor, and a good survey of early 19th century motor tech.  I do not believe Taylor's invention was for a "reluctance motor": the title and premise of your question is based on an urban legend.

Comment: It's starting to make sense now. Thank you for that link. It shows a progression, step by step. Just what I was looking for.